# Toggling table rows to hide/show in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table which I would like to have a button onClick which will run the toggle() function

at the moment, I can hide the M values but not bring them back,

lets say for example this is how the table looked

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  | Gender |
+-------+--------+
| James | M      |
+-------+--------+
| Gemma | F      |
+-------+--------+
| John  | F      |
+-------+--------+
```

heres the toggle function

```
function toggle() {
    var searchString = 'M';
    $("#t01 tr td:contains('" + searchString  + "')").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == searchString) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to go from the `tr` and inspect inside like below:-

```js
function toggle(gender) {
  $('#t01 tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($('td:eq(1):contains(' + gender + ')', this).length > 0);
  })
}

function show() {
  $('#t01 tbody tr').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="t01">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gemma</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="toggle('M')">Male</button>
<button onclick="toggle('F')">Female</button>
<button onclick="show()">All</button>
```

Comment: thanks, this is what im looking for, however how would I make it so that if i press "male" again, it will bring back the females, or if there was a button which said "both" and it showed both male and female together again

Comment: just saw shubhams comment, his is more what i was looking for, thanks for the assistance

Comment: Added the All options for reference.

Comment: ps. dont forget to use `:eq(1)` as that says to only inspect the gender td (index 1). otherwise if a name had M/F it would validate true.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working properly for hiding the row then you can simply replace hide() with toggle() to show/hide keeping the rest same, or you can simplify the code as told by BG101.

```
function toggle() {
    var searchString = 'M';
    $("#t01 tr td:contains('" + searchString  + "')").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == searchString) {
            $(this).parent().toggle();
        }  
    });
}
```